# create virtual adaptor over network on other machine

Tags: linux, networking

I have Machine A (Desktop environment install/Powerful machine) running Linux that has all my programs, scripts etc on it.

I connect to machine B (Voyage Linux (Debian)/ALIX pc engines) over ethernet using ssh.  No problem here.

What I want to know is how/if I can "create an adaptor"  on B from A and be able to run all my commands/scripts over the network/ssh using the adaptor on machine B as if it where on A, i.e programs scripts etc.

So maybe something like `# ethB:192.168.1.x`

Comment: I don't understand what it is you want to do, just something about how it should be implemented. So this feels like an XY problem: I want to do Y but I'm asking X. It would help if you have a specific scenario of commands you want to run, and how it is that having this be a device makes it work while using an IP address or DNS name doesn't.

Comment: Rocky -
I would like to know if it is possible to create a "virtual NIC"... I have a small remote machine (alix) which has eth0 and wlan0.
 Everything is connected via Ethernet.



I would like to be able to run my scripts locally (because all programs scripts can be run from a GUI) but on the remote NIC. 

I am not sure what the best scenario would be.

Comment: Restating what you say in the question isn't clarification. Be specific. Give specific commands you want to work that take device names. Other than things like tcpdump or wireshark, commands do not generally refer to NICs.

Answer (score 0):

VPN's create "virtual adaptors". For example look at information on [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html). I've also created a VPN using [ssh and PPP](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/ppp-ssh/).